# CSS how to align vertically center div floating elements of menu?

Tags: html, css, alignment, center, vertical-alignment

I am writing menu with multiline . I used div container and floating divs with . Here is code: [click for code on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/42w0wde9/1/)
or look here for code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #menu {
            width: 1000px;
            height: 55px;
            border: 1px solid green;
            background-color: green;
        }

        .element_menu {
            width: 100px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            font-size: 11pt;
        }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="element_menu"><a href="#">Strona<br />Główna</a></div>
        <div class="element_menu"><a href="#">Kontakt</a></div>
        <div class="element_menu"><a href="#">Tygodniowy plan<br />pracy</a></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to align menu text to center vertically. How to do this?

EDIT: Borders of .element_menu is for test.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/42w0wde9/2/   are you looking to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add display: table-cell and vertical-align:middle to your element_menu class and remove the float:left

code snippet here...

```css
#menu {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 55px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: green;
}
.element_menu {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  /*float: left;*/
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11pt;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div class="element_menu"><a href="#">Strona<br />Główna</a>
  </div>
  <div class="element_menu"><a href="#">Kontakt</a>
  </div>
  <div class="element_menu"><a href="#">Tygodniowy plan<br />pracy</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this was what you were looking for.